# Dropdown not working Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, django-templates

I am using Django for the second time, and I am trying to have a base html file for just the header that I can import in my other pages. The problem is the drop down part does not seem to be working. I can't find the problem in my code. maybe. Here is my code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top example-8">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar8">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="#">Brand Text
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar8" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
<!--/.container-fluid -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap dropdowns only work if you are importing the bootstrap javascript file into your HTML, your example does not show any imports.

Something like:

```
<script src="path/to/boostrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this but it still does not seem to work. Thanks for the advice tho.

Comment: The hint with `path/to/` really helped! Apparently, having the same issue, I imported the `min.js` not from the same version of Bootstrap that I had imported previously. So, the `path/to/` really helped realizing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem once occurred with me.
The solution was:

I was including the bootstrap `CDN s` in both the pages i.e files so it was not working.
Check whether you are doing the same thing. Try using the cdn s only on main pages not in the header include file.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I remember that but it still did not work. Thanks for the hint tho